# css positioning,effect on top and height when background-position is bottom

Tags: html, css, background-position

can somebody explain the concept of `background-position:bottom;`
I have HTML & CSS :

```css
body {
  position:relative;
  background:#333;
}
div {
  display:block;
  border:1px solid red;
  width:400px;
  height: 600px;
  position:relative;
 }

span {
  background: url("http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/m1.png") no-repeat;
  position:absolute;
  background-position:bottom;
  top: 0;bottom: 0;left: 0;right: 0;
  height:50px;
  top:auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

1- why `background-position` is measured with respect to parent DIV not span ? as if you set `background-position:top;` it goes to top edge of div and so on ?

2 - when  `background-position:bottom;` then why `height:50px` is calculated from bottom in normal cases it is calculated from top,notice that I have not shifted transform origin here

3- I am using the `top: 0;bottom: 0;left: 0;right: 0;` to get the exact height and length as parent div,I set height 50 which is calculated from bottom and if now I set `top:auto` then why the portion of image is moved to bottom,it should have been to bottom without this property as `background-position:bottom;` is already set.

Answer (score 2):

Lets first understand what is `background-position`:

> The background-position property sets the starting position of a
>   background image.

1.`background-position` is measured with respect to the image and not with the container `span` or parent `div`.

2.The height is calculated from bottom as it is **absolute positioned** element with `bottom` as **0**.So its placed at **bottom** of its parent `div`.

3.As you have given `top` as **0** so the `span` is sticking to **top** of its parent `div`.So when u change the `top` value to **auto**.It sticks to **bottom** of its parent `div` as `bottom` value is **0**.The **positioning** of `span` has **nothing** to do with `background-image`

Comment: Thanks for clarification ! 
One more thing, suppose I have only one element in my html lets say :<p>lorem ipsum</p>
And now if I  set width and height of this p tag to 200*200 then how can I move my text at the desired location I want, suppose bottom-center, I don't want to use text-align property.

Comment: give following **css** in <p> `display: flex;align-items: flex-end;text-align:center;`

Answer (score 0):

Just one thing I want to clear here with my experiment that:

**1- background position is measured with respect to its container for which background is set and it tells the image that where it should sit in its container.**

**2- here height is not being calculated from the bottom for the image, although it's giving that illusion that it's being measured from there.**

**we are giving height only to the container span here and since the image is said to be sits at the bottom of its parent container span that is why here we can see only the bottom portion of the image, and with the top:auto we are pushing span container to the bottom of its parent div.**